# SUM rows when had same categories until the sum is 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do a query which sum a total colum when the value of the same categories do 1.

Example

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      categoria      |    categoria 2   |       valor      |       Total      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          a          |         a        |        0.2       |        20        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          a          |         a        |        0.2       |        42        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          a          |         a        |        0.2       |        46        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          a          |         a        |        0.2       |        23        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          a          |         a        |        0.2       |         6        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          a          |         a        |        0.7       |        30        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          a          |         a        |        0.3       |        30        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          b          |         c        |        0.6       |        80        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          c          |         b        |        0.4       |        54        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          c          |         b        |        0.6       |        23        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

What I wanned

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      categoria      |    categoria 2   |       valor      |       Total      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          a          |         a        |         1        |        137       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          a          |         a        |         1        |        60        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          c          |         b        |         1        |        77        |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Can be many rows but with max 1 in value
I'm using some like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  c.category,
  c.category2,
  sum(c.value),
  sum(c.total)
FROM dbo.categoryTable
GROUP BY c.category, category2
HAVING sum(c.value) >= 1
```

Comment: No need to do `SELECT DISTINCT`, the `GROUP BY` returns no duplicates.

Comment: You select `c.category` twice. Typo here?

Comment: How are you determining the order of the summing; I can see no obvious way to get the data out in your sample data in that order using `ORDER BY`. Also, what happens if you have a number that tips you over 1. For example, `0.3`, `0.3`, `0.5` (`= 1.1`).

Comment: @jarlh Thanks I'm gonna remove `DISTINCT` and the second category is `category2` , let me correct the question. Thanks :)

Comment: @Larnu I only want to use the ones with `1` , Thanks for answer

Comment: In SQL there's no way to stop and start a new group with the same "key"  (category, category2) as before as soon as sum(value) = 1. You'll have to write a program to get the desired result

Comment: You may do it using a recursive cte. But you need a field to order the data. And as Lamu said. You need to explain how handling when value go over 1.0

Comment: Really solving this problem requires a recursive CTE.  If you just want the first occurrence for each category, then that is doable with a simpler query.  I should also note that you need a column specifying the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

As already briefly addressed in my comment, I'll try to give a more explicit answer here.

Your main problem is that the requirement is ill defined.
Say you have a bunch of rows like

```
1. a, a, 0.1, 0.1
2. a, a, 0.2, 0.2
3. a, a, 0.3, 0.3
4. a, a, 0.4, 0.4
5. a, a, 0.5, 0.5
6. a, a, 0.6, 0.6
7. a, a, 0.7, 0.7
8. a, a, 0.8, 0.8
9. a, a, 0.9, 0.9
```

It is now not defined if you'd like to have

```
1+9, 2+8, 3+7, 4+6:
a, a, 1, 1 -- 4 times
```

or

```
1+2+3+4:
a, a, 1, 1 -- 1 time
```

or

```
2+3+5, 4+6, 1+9:
a, a, 1, 1 -- 3 times
```

or

```
1+3+6, 2+8:
a, a, 1, 1 -- 2 times
```

It is relatively hard to find all subsets of a set of numbers that sum up to a certain value. And then find the set of subsets that are disjoint, such that the maximum number of elements of the original set is used.

That's a bit much to ask from a language like SQL.

Answer (score 0):

This gets you there. Given a few hours you could make it more efficient. This is pretty messy, however, I don't have time to tweak on it today.

Note, using `LEAD()` or `LAG()` could condense this down a bit, however, my laptop is still running 2008.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    Categoria NVARCHAR(10),
    Categoria2 NVARCHAR(10),
    Valor DECIMAL(18,2),
    Total INT
)
INSERT @T SELECT 'a','a',0.2,20
INSERT @T SELECT 'a','a',0.2,42
INSERT @T SELECT 'a','a',0.2,46
INSERT @T SELECT 'a','a',0.2,23
INSERT @T SELECT 'a','a',0.2,6
INSERT @T SELECT 'a','a',0.7,30
INSERT @T SELECT 'a','a',0.3,30
INSERT @T SELECT 'b','c',0.6,80
INSERT @T SELECT 'c','b',0.4,54
INSERT @T SELECT 'c','b',0.6,23

;
WITH GetRowNumber AS
(   
    SELECT
        This.Categoria,This.Categoria2,Valor,Total,
        RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY This.categoria, This.Categoria2)
    FROM
        @T This
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT Categoria,Categoria2,SumValor=SUM(Valor)
            FROM @T     
            GROUP BY Categoria,Categoria2
            HAVING SUM(Valor) >=1
        )AS That ON That.Categoria=This.Categoria AND That.Categoria2=This.Categoria2
),
 RunningSum AS
(
    SELECT
        RowNumber= This.RowNumber,
        SumValor = SUM(That.Valor)
    FROM
        GetRowNumber This
        LEFT OUTER JOIN GetRowNumber That ON This.RowNumber > That.RowNumber
    GROUP BY
        This.Categoria,This.Categoria2,This.Valor,This.Total,This.RowNumber
),
BoundryMarkersNoGrouped AS
(
    SELECT 
        RowNumber=This.RowNumber,
        Boundry=FLOOR(That.SumValor + This.Valor)
    FROM 
        GetRowNumber This
        LEFT OUTER JOIN RunningSum That ON This.RowNumber = That.RowNUmber
    WHERE
        FLOOR(That.SumValor + This.Valor) > 0
),
BoundryMarkers AS
(
    SELECT
        Boundry, 
        BoundryRowNumber = MIN(RowNUmber)
    FROM 
        BoundryMarkersNoGrouped 
    GROUP BY
        Boundry
),
LowHigh AS
(
    SELECT 
        HighBoundry = This.BoundryRowNumber,
        LowBoundry = COALESCE( MAX(That.BoundryRowNumber) +1 , 1)
    FROM 
        BoundryMarkers This
        LEFT OUTER JOIN BoundryMarkers That ON That.Boundry < This.Boundry
    GROUP BY
        This.BoundryRowNumber   
)

SELECT
    Categoria,
    Categoria2,
    Valor=SUM(Valor),
    Total=SUM(Total)
FROM
    GetRowNumber D  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN LowHigh ON D.RowNumber BETWEEN LowHigh.LowBoundry AND LowHigh.HighBoundry
GROUP BY
    Categoria,
    Categoria2,
    LowHigh.LowBoundry
```